# Resetting Bluetooth Audio dongle without disconnect?

Tags: sound, usb, 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS, and now I have an USB BT audio dongle which behaves quite odd:

1.) I have to disconnect and reconnect physically every single time when I wish it to rejoin to its paired BT speaker.

2.) I have to keep open `pavucontrol` to limit the sampling frequency down to 44.1kHz, otherwise YouTube videos don't play back well (they play 2.5x speed, due to this dongle defaulting to 96kHz).

3.) There is no control interface for this device

4.) Bluetooth is not detecting it as a device

Now I don't really know if #4 is a real concern/problem, as I don't have experience with BT Audio. Shall it be considered as a BT device, so shall Ubuntu's stock BT setting see it? Currently it says I don't have any Bluetooth attached to my computer.

Now #3 is a real concern and slightly coupled to #1: I wish to NOT physically plugging/removing every single time when I bootup the computer or turn on the speaker.

Problem #2 I can solve by running pulseaudio as a service, just I wanted to list it here for sake of completeness.

So main question in general: are BT Audio dongles having some interface on Ubuntu to control them (i.e. start pairing mode, list paired devices, connect to a paired device, etc)?

Comment: Check the output of `usbreset`? ... Can you see your dongle in it?

Comment: I can see it there yes. But `usbreset` when I use it on this dongle doesn't have the same effect as unplug then replug (ie. dongle is not going to connect to its last paired device).

Comment: There is no way to reset without pulling out the device as you cannot cut the +5V power to the port.  Some USB hubs have been known to be able to do it, but as far as a motherboard USB port goes, you can't cut the power so there is no way to do the same reset as unplugging then replugging back in.

Comment: Was this sold as a combo, headset and dongle?

Comment: No, it's a dongle only. And it works, just I have to unplug then replug every single time.